# ResultSet and the SQL functions

Tags: java, sql, derby, resultset

I am using Derby database, and would like to know something: is a `ResultSet` a table? If so, that means I could invoke `MIN(ResultSet.someColumn)` (or `MAX()` or `AVG()`), right? Or would I have to dump the `ResultSet` to a temporary table to use the desired SQL functions?

Comment: an instance of ResultSet is a java object. while MIN() and MAX() are SQL functions you cannot do MIN(ResultSet.someColumn)

Comment: So, I would have to write the rows that ResultSet contains to a temporary table, and then use those functions? That or use a while-loop to fetch the information, and just perform the `min()`, `max()`, `avg()` from Java?

Comment: Why write it in temporary table? create a SQL which directly gives you end result. Post your SQL here on SO if you are stuck

Comment: You do realize that I have already solved this problem? See the responses to the accepted answer...

Comment: ya I read the answer but not comments. apologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) , a ResultSet is:

> A table of data representing a database result set, which is usually generated by executing a statement that queries the database.

If you want to apply some aggregate function, you will have to modify your SQL statement and then re-execute it. Finally, you will be provided with a ResultSet (eventhough it may contain a single row).

Comment: So maybe go from something like `SELECT * FROM IntegerModeData WHERE Difficulty=5` to `SELECT MIN(Completion_Time) FROM (SELECT * FROM IntegerModeData WHERE Difficulty=5)`, which when made a String argument of `Statement.executeQuery()`, which will return ResultSet of only one row and one column! That will do all my work for me! F**king genius!!

Comment: and alas, it doesn't work with Derby. It complains that EOF was encountered on last character of command String. :(

Comment: Wait a second. I am missing five characters: "AS CS". I don't know what the heck it even means, but i see it as a working example somewhere on the Derby website....

Comment: The SQL "AS" keyword allows you to give names to the intermediate results of a query. You can name the intermediate tables and columns, which helps you refer to them in outer queries.